# 3 related Entity Tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Can I display data from a 3 entity related tables to a Gridview using EntityDataSource?
Is it possible?

For example:

Currency Table

```
ID - 1
NAME - JPY
```

Ticket Table

```
ID - 1
NameId - 2
Time - 08:00AM
```

User Table

```
ID - 2
CurrencyID - 1
Name - JESSY
```

I want to display this in gridview:

```
JESSY JPY 8:00AM
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by join.After join put joined result set on a container and bind this container with grid

In all your table one column is common it's ID - 1

```
 var result=from p in User  
join q in Ticket on p.ID equals q.ID
join r in Currency on p.ID equals r.ID
select new {p.name,r.Name,q.Time}//Here you can get any column of ralated three tables
```

grid.Datasource=result

Hope above syntax ,will give you idea .How to solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you. appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can select users and grab the name of the associated currency entity and the time of the associated ticket entity. So long as your foreign keys and associations are set up, you can use navigation properties and create an anonymous object like this. Then, put the results into your gridview.

```
var results = Users.Select(x => 
       new { 
              Name = x.name, 
              Currency = x.Currency.Name, 
              Time = x.Ticket.Time 
       }).ToList();
```